# Set ruby path for run model function using whenever gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, whenever

In my rails application, i want to run model function using whenever gem.
My schedule.rb file like,

```
set :environment, 'development'
set :output, "#{path}/log/cron.log"
set :job_template, "bash -l -c ':job'"
job_type :runner,  "cd :path && bin/rails runner -e :environment ':task' :output"

every 2.minutes do
  runner "Book.jobrun"
end

every 2.minutes do
    command "echo 'rink4'"
end
```

And book.rb model like,

```
self.jobrun
  Rails.logger.info "cronjob is running"
end
```

But when i run cronjob, in cron.log file showing,

```
bin/rails:3: undefined method `require_relative' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

How i need to set ruby path or rails path?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `which ruby` from cron. Is it as you expect? If not, cron is likly defaulting to system Ruby which in your case is probably version 1.8.7 and doesn't have the `require_relative` function.

Check which ruby executble you're using with `which ruby`. And use this in the shebang at the top of your bin/rails. for instance

**bin/rails**

```
#!/Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby.
```